# Transforming Kinect coordinates to character model

Tags: animation, xna, kinect

I have the latest Kinect SDK, XNA 4.0, and a model with a skeleton and I'm looking into working with the kinect to create some simple games. I heard that various engines, such as the DigitalRune engine provide an easy way to map the skeleton generated from the Kinect sensor to the skeleton of the model.

Which engine is the best for this task and why? I'd prefer if you could list both the best free engine and the one you have to pay for, as well as any additional suggestion, should you have them.

I really need help with this. While I did manage to find about five engines that might suit my needs (Ploobs, Engine Nine, DigitalRune, Hilva, Xen, XNA Final Engine) I have no way of telling which is better than the other, as there is very little activity in the related forums and I really don't have the time (or, more importantly, the knowledge) to test all these engines.

Answer (score 0):

I think XNA is better, because it gives more transparency when it comes to game programming, there is no doubt it is the most used for game programming and as a plus point you will have tons of tutorials. xna framework will be best even you can have e-books too.